# Strange Symfony syntax

Tags: php, html, twig, symfony

I've joined new project of website in Symfony3 framework and now I'm struggling an issue, trying to figure out this particular syntax in Twig:

```
<li><a href="{{ path('contact') }}">{{ 'site.template.menu.contact'|trans }}</a></li>
```

Arguments in path() twig function have name of route in my SiteController but i totally don't know what does code between `<a/>` tags, except 'trans' filter. I don't have any variables in my twig template file.

Have you seen something like this before? Where I should find information about this in docs or how to name syntax like this to find some information?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html talks about the `{{ }}` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just the twig "internationalization" (often abbreviated i18n).
Docs for it are [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html).
The quotes around the object shouldn't be there. I'm assuming that an object called `site` is being passed to the view, so it should be `{{ site.template.menu.contact|trans }}`

To explain the dot notation in twig;
If your PHP array is something like;

```
$site['template']['menu']['contact'] = 'fubar';
```

If it is an object then it is just attributes of the object.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! However I want to know where refers this line with Dot notation: 'site.template.menu.contact'?

Comment: @MichaelKowalewsky in your controller that call the view, just `dump($site)` to see what the object is and what it contains.

Comment: I don't think that is an object, but a string to be translated. This is common, using identifiers for tranlsation keys instead of the site's primary language.